# fail to show allert " No data" when data is does not in database

Tags: laravel

i am using laravel 5.4 ,, i use filter by serial number, i want to when the serial number is not save in database, show the allert "no data" , but when i filter data serial number is not save to database, the page is not show the allert,,

[image: allert not show]

this is my blade..

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
......................................

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    @if (!$instrumentType->instruments->isEmpty())
      <table class="table">
        @foreach ($instruments as $instrument)
          <tr>
            <td>
              Serial Number : {{ $instrument->serial_number }}
              @if($instrument->customer !== NULL)
              <div class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-hospital-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  {{ $instrument->customer->name }}</div>
              @endif
              @if($instrument->contractType !== NULL)
              <div class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-compress" aria-hidden="true"></i>  {{ $instrument->contractType->name }}</div>
              @endif
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="pull-right">
                <a type="button" href="{{ route('instrument.edit', ['instrumentType' => $instrumentType->id, 'instrument' => $instrument->id]) }}"
                  class="btn btn-success ">
                  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit
                </a>
                  @if($instrument->customer == NULL || $instrument->contractType == NULL)
                  <a href="{{ route('instrument.destroy', ['instrumentType' => $instrumentType->id, 'instrument' => $instrument->id]) }}"
                    data-method="delete" data-confirm="" class="btn btn-danger">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <span class="hidden-xs">Delete</span>
                  </a>
                  @endif
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
      </table>
      <div class="paginator text-center">{{ $instruments->links() }}</div>
      @else
          <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="alert alert-warning text-center">No data.</div>
      </div>
    @endif

    </div>
@endsection
```

.

Answer (score 0):

you can get count of array with :

```
count($instrumentType->instruments)
```

add this code as your statement :

```
@if(count($instrumentType->instruments))
//
@else
//
@endif
```